# Getting various LabelFrame widgets in th same grid's row together

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've been working on a welcome window for my app and I can't seem to get the LabelFrames on the last row together on the [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lVYD.png). I've tried configuring the `column weight`, by adding `padx` and by eliminating the `columnspan`, buth nothing seems to work and the `LabelFrame` widgets keep the same distance.

The `Frame` has `grid` packing and in the last `row` the `LabelFrames` are placed.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkf

    class ventana_inicio(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,controller,dbs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,controller)
        self.pack()
        self.controller=controller
        self.db_state=dbs

        lblmuc=tk.Label(self,text="MAMOOTS ULTIMATE CLUB",font=tkf.Font(family="Arial Black",size="20"))
        lbl98=tk.Label(self,text="Alive since 1998",font=tkf.Font(family="Segoe Script",slant="italic"))
        lblbla=tk.Label(self,text="Version 1.0 // 2020",font=tkf.Font(family="Arial Black",size="8"),width=20)
    
        lbfDB=tk.LabelFrame(self,text="SQL")
        btnIDB=tk.Button(lbfDB,text="Iniciar")
        btnCDB=tk.Button(lbfDB,text="Cargar")
        btnBDB=tk.Button(lbfDB,text="Borrar")

        lbfinf=tk.LabelFrame(self,text="Aplicación")
        btnIAP=tk.Button(lbfinf,text="Iniciar")
        btnLAP=tk.Button(lbfinf,text="Ver Log")

        lfbst=tk.LabelFrame(self,text="Estado")
        btnst=tk.Button(lfbst,text="Revisar")

        lblmuc.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6)
        lbl98.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=6)
        lblbla.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=6)
        lbfDB.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=5)
        lbfinf.grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=2,padx=5)
        lfbst.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=5)

        btnIDB.grid(row=0,column=0)
        btnCDB.grid(row=0,column=1)
        btnBDB.grid(row=0,column=2)

        btnIAP.grid(row=0,column=0)
        btnLAP.grid(row=0,column=1)

        btnst.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Comment: Try putting the `LabelFrames` in another `Frame` which is laid out using `grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `sticky` attribute to tell each labelframe to "stick" to the edges of the space they have been given.

```
lbfDB.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=sticky="ew")
lbfinf.grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=2,padx=5, sticky="ew")
lfbst.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=5, sticky="ew")
```